# Adding moko resources dependencies to compose multiplatform project

Tags: resources, kotlin-multiplatform, sharing, compose-multiplatform

I'm getting the following error when trying to add moko resource dependencies to my compose multiplatform project
`Resolving dependency configuration 'metadataCompilationApi' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'. Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'metadataCompilationApi' should be resolved.`

here is my build.gradle.kts

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.kapt.incremental.metadataDescriptor
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.dependsOnClosure
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DummyFrameworkTask

plugins {

    alias(libs.plugins.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.buildConfig)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinx.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqlDelight)

    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")

}


kotlin {

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
            export("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.22.3")
            export("dev.icerock.moko:graphics:0.9.0")
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings {
                optIn("org.jetbrains.compose.resources.ExperimentalResourceApi")
            }
        }


        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.material3)
                implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                implementation(compose.ui)
                @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)



                implementation(libs.voyager.navigator)
                implementation(libs.voyager.screen.model)
                implementation(libs.voyager.livedata)
                implementation(libs.voyager.bottomSheet.navigator)
//             Screen Model
//             implementation(libs.composeImageLoader)
                implementation(libs.napier)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                implementation(libs.moko.mvvm)
                implementation(libs.ktor.core)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
                implementation(libs.multiplatformSettings)
            }
        }

        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test"))
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
                implementation(libs.androidx.activityCompose)
                implementation(libs.compose.uitooling)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.android)
            }


        }
        val iosArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosArm64Test by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }

    }


}

android {
    namespace = "irancell.nwg.wfm"
    compileSdk = 34


    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34

        applicationId = "irancell.nwg.wfm.androidApp"
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"
    }
    sourceSets["main"].apply {
        manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
        res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/resources")
        resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"
    }
}



sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("MyDatabase") {
            // Database configuration here.
            // https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight
            packageName.set("irancell.nwg.wfm.db")
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    commonMainApi(libs.bundles.moko.resources)
}


multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "irancell.nwg.wfm"
}
```

and my build.gradle.kts of composeApp module :

```
import org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.kapt.incremental.metadataDescriptor
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.sources.dependsOnClosure
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.DummyFrameworkTask

plugins {

    alias(libs.plugins.multiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.compose)
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.buildConfig)
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinx.serialization)
    alias(libs.plugins.sqlDelight)

    id("dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources")

}


kotlin {

    androidTarget {
        compilations.all {
            kotlinOptions {
                jvmTarget = "17"
            }
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach {
        it.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
            export("dev.icerock.moko:resources:0.22.3")
            export("dev.icerock.moko:graphics:0.9.0")
        }
    }


    sourceSets {
        all {
            languageSettings {
                optIn("org.jetbrains.compose.resources.ExperimentalResourceApi")
            }
        }


        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.material3)
                implementation(compose.materialIconsExtended)
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.foundation)
                implementation(compose.material)
                implementation(compose.ui)
                @OptIn(ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)



                implementation(libs.voyager.navigator)
                implementation(libs.voyager.screen.model)
                implementation(libs.voyager.livedata)
                implementation(libs.voyager.bottomSheet.navigator)
//             Screen Model
//             implementation(libs.composeImageLoader)
                implementation(libs.napier)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                implementation(libs.moko.mvvm)
                implementation(libs.ktor.core)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
                implementation(libs.multiplatformSettings)
            }
        }

        commonTest.dependencies {
            implementation(kotlin("test"))
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)
            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
                implementation(libs.androidx.activityCompose)
                implementation(libs.compose.uitooling)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.android)
            }


        }
        val iosArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosArm64Test by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosX64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }
        val iosSimulatorArm64Main by getting {
            dependsOn(commonMain)

            dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
                implementation(libs.sqlDelight.driver.native)
            }
        }

    }


}

android {
    namespace = "irancell.nwg.wfm"
    compileSdk = 34


    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = 24
        targetSdk = 34

        applicationId = "irancell.nwg.wfm.androidApp"
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0.0"
    }
    sourceSets["main"].apply {
        manifest.srcFile("src/androidMain/AndroidManifest.xml")
        res.srcDirs("src/androidMain/resources")
        resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }

    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.4"
    }
}



sqldelight {
    databases {
        create("MyDatabase") {
            // Database configuration here.
            // https://cashapp.github.io/sqldelight
            packageName.set("irancell.nwg.wfm.db")
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    commonMainApi(libs.bundles.moko.resources)
}


multiplatformResources {
    multiplatformResourcesPackage = "irancell.nwg.wfm"
}
```

and my libs.version.toml:

```
[versions]

kotlin = "1.9.21"
agp = "8.2.0"
compose = "1.5.11"

androidx-appcompat = "1.6.1"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.8.1"
compose-uitooling = "1.5.4"
voyager = "1.0.0"
composeImageLoader = "1.7.1"
napier = "2.6.1"
buildConfig = "4.1.1"
kotlinx-coroutines = "1.7.3"
moko-mvvm = "0.16.1"
ktor = "2.3.7"
kotlinx-serialization = "1.6.2"
multiplatformSettings = "1.1.1"
sqlDelight = "2.0.1"

moko-version = "0.23.0"

[libraries]
androidx-appcompat = { module = "androidx.appcompat:appcompat", version.ref = "androidx-appcompat" }
androidx-activityCompose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
compose-uitooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose-uitooling" }
voyager-navigator = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-navigator", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-screen-model = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-screenmodel", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-livedata = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-livedata", version.ref = "voyager" }
voyager-bottomSheet_navigator = { module = "cafe.adriel.voyager:voyager-bottom-sheet-navigator", version.ref = "voyager" }
composeImageLoader = { module = "io.github.qdsfdhvh:image-loader", version.ref = "composeImageLoader" }
napier = { module = "io.github.aakira:napier", version.ref = "napier" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "kotlinx-coroutines" }
kotlinx-coroutines-android = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android", version.ref = "kotlinx-coroutines" }
moko-mvvm = { module = "dev.icerock.moko:mvvm-compose", version.ref = "moko-mvvm" }
ktor-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktor" }
ktor-client-okhttp = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp", version.ref = "ktor" }
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "kotlinx-serialization" }
multiplatformSettings = { module = "com.russhwolf:multiplatform-settings", version.ref = "multiplatformSettings" }
sqlDelight-driver-sqlite = { module = "app.cash.sqldelight:sqlite-driver", version.ref = "sqlDelight" }
sqlDelight-driver-android = { module = "app.cash.sqldelight:android-driver", version.ref = "sqlDelight" }
sqlDelight-driver-native = { module = "app.cash.sqldelight:native-driver", version.ref = "sqlDelight" }
sqlDelight-driver-js = { module = "app.cash.sqldelight:web-worker-driver", version.ref = "sqlDelight" }

moko-classpath =  {group = "dev.icerock.moko", name = "resources-generator", version.ref = "moko-version"}
moko-resource = {group = "dev.icerock.moko", name = "resources", version.ref = "moko-version"}
moko-resource-compose = {group = "dev.icerock.moko", name = "resources-compose", version.ref = "moko-version"}

[plugins]
moko-multiplatform = {id="dev.icerock.mobile.multiplatform-resources", version.ref = "moko-version"}
multiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
compose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose" }
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
buildConfig = { id = "com.github.gmazzo.buildconfig", version.ref = "buildConfig" }
kotlinx-serialization = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.serialization", version.ref = "kotlin" }
sqlDelight = { id = "app.cash.sqldelight", version.ref = "sqlDelight" }


[bundles]
moko-resources = ["moko-resource", "moko-resource-compose"]
```

gradle.properties:

```
#Gradle
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options\="-Xmx2048M"
org.gradle.caching=true
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true

#Kotlin
kotlin.code.style=official
kotlin.js.compiler=ir


#Compose
org.jetbrains.compose.experimental.uikit.enabled=true
org.jetbrains.compose.experimental.jscanvas.enabled=true

#Android
android.useAndroidX=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
kotlin.native.ignoreDisabledTargets=true




#Kotlin

#MPP
kotlin.mpp.stability.nowarn=true
kotlin.mpp.enableCInteropCommonization=true
kotlin.mpp.androidSourceSetLayoutVersion=2


#Android
android.compileSdk=34
android.targetSdk=34
android.minSdk=24

#Versions
kotlin.version=1.9.10
agp.version=8.1.1
compose.version=1.5.4

org.jetbrains.compose.experimental.macos.enabled=true
kotlin.mpp.applyDefaultHierarchyTemplate=false
```

settings.gradle.kts:

```
rootProject.name = "WFM"
include(":composeApp")


pluginManagement {

    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")

    }

    plugins {
        val kotlinVersion = extra["kotlin.version"] as String
        val agpVersion = extra["agp.version"] as String
        val composeVersion = extra["compose.version"] as String

        kotlin("jvm").version(kotlinVersion)
        kotlin("multiplatform").version(kotlinVersion)
        kotlin("android").version(kotlinVersion)

        id("com.android.application").version(agpVersion)
        id("com.android.library").version(agpVersion)

        id("org.jetbrains.compose").version(composeVersion)
        id("com.android.library") version "8.1.1"
        id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10"
    }
}

plugins {

    id("org.gradle.toolchains.foojay-resolver-convention") version("0.4.0")
}

dependencyResolutionManagement {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/compose/dev")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to build my project but the following error happens:

```
Resolving dependency configuration 'metadataCompilationApi' is not allowed as it is defined as 'canBeResolved=false'.
Instead, a resolvable ('canBeResolved=true') dependency configuration that extends 'metadataCompilationApi' should be resolved.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line:

```
org.gradle.configuration-cache=true
```

in `gradle.properties`.